# Expandable ListView and cursor adapter

Tags: android

I have a ListView which uses cursor adapter to show the records from database. When a new records is inserted in database ,it works great and shows that entry on top of ListView on requery.

Now I am facing problem when User scroll down the List, background thread call web service and brings old data. In this case when it does requery, old data is also getting appended on top of list which should append old data at the end of list.

What should i need to do differently, to add old data at the end of List rather than top ? do i need to change method of insertion when I am getting this old data ?

Comment: How are you filling your cursor data in the expandable list? Are you using or creating a new contend provider to access your database?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to store a date field in your bd table and make an ORDER BY in the query....